# Convert multiple AVI files to JPEG

Tags: r, jpeg, avi

I am trying to convert multiple (250 or so) `.avi` video files into `.jpeg` files with R.

I have managed to convert single `.avi` files using function `av_video_images()` from library `av`, but I would love to know how to iterate this over multiple input files.

```r
av::av_video_images("FILE001.AVI", destdir = "Site_1_JPEG", format = "jpg", fps = 1)
```

I have the 250 `.avi` files in a folder and would like all frames produced in the output folder `Site_1_JPEG`.

Comment: Assuming you have a vector of the file names called `fnames`, then `sapply(fnames, function(x) av_video_images(x, destdir = "Site_1_JPEG", format = "jpg", fps = 1)` should do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have a vector of the file names, but it seems to be throwing the error length(video) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: Does it convert any of the files? Try `av_video_images(fnames[1], destdir = "Site_1_JPEG", format = "jpg", fps = 1)` to see if it converts the first name. Do you have a vector of file names or a data frame containing a column of file names. That would definitely make a difference.

Comment: Hey, if I use the `av_video_images(fnames[1]...` as you suggested it will convert the first of the 263 files into JPEGS. fnames is a vector I made using `fnames <- list.files(pattern = "*.AVI")`. If I convert just one file it works fine but when I try multiple it throws the error `length(video) == 1 is not TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution since I cannot reproduce your issue, but I think it will get you closer. Your example suggests that the files you want to process are in your current working directory. Secondly, your code will not produce the desired results because `av_video_images` names the .jpg files as "image_000001.jpg", "image_000002.jpg", "image_000003.jpg" and I see no way to alter the names of the extracted jpg's. That means your code will successively overwrite the previous files and at the end you will only have the final set of jpg's. To prevent that you need to create separate folders for each video file. Here is one solution:

```
library(av)
sapply(flist[1:3], function(x) av_video_images(paste0(path, x), x, fps=.5))
```

To test the code I specified that only the first 3 files will be processed to check things out. There are two differences between my code and yours. First my video files are located in a different directory (`path`) so I pasted the path onto the file name. Second I provided a different destination directory for each file which is just the file name. This produced three folders with jpg files in each.

The error message could indicate that one or more of the .avi files is corrupt. You can get the directory information on all of the files with

```
file.info(flist)
```

The main thing to look at is the size column to make sure the size is large enough.